# PHP object serialization and unserialization not working properly

Tags: php, serialization

I have 3 source files as follows:

first one is source_class.php

```
class MacMini
{
    public $memory = "16 Gigabytes";
    public $cpu = "Intel Core i7 @ 2.6GHz";
    public $HD = "1TB @ 5200 rpms";
    public function mem()
    {
        return $this->memory;
    }
    public function centralPU()
    {
        return $this->cpu;
    }
    public function hard_drive()
    {
        return $this->HD;
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

second one is serialize.php

```
include "source_class.php";
$myMini = new MacMini;
$myMini->cpu = "Intel Core i7 @ 3.4GHz";
$serialized = serialize($myMini);
file_put_contents("store", $serialized);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////

third one is unserialize.php

```
include "source_class.php";
$data = file_get_contents("store");
$unserialized = unserialize($data);

$myMini = new MacMini;
echo $myMini->cpu;
```

it produces the following output:
"Intel Core i7 @ 2.6GHz"

Why, if the property of the cpu was changed in the serialize.php file, is it not reflected in the unserialization? I checked the raw data contents of the serialized file, "store" and the cpu property is reflected in the serialized file but when it's unserialized in unserialize.php the property change is not reflected. Why is that? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new `$myMini` object and output the `cpu` properity of this newly created object. The serialization/ unserialization doesn't make sense this way.

Change *unserialize.php* to :

```
include "source_class.php";
$data = file_get_contents("store");
$myMini = unserialize($data);

echo $myMini->cpu;
```

Comment: Ooh now I understand. I should've caught the logic of why. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. This is the sort of errors because one should compare delivered hardware against ordered hardware when purchasing online. :) hehe